# What is the little box accepting text in lower right of Ubuntu 1204

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-12.04

I recently installed ubuntu 1204.  The lock screen key is supposed to be <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> but when I press that combination a little text box opens in the lower right corner and it gets the input 'l'.  Pressing enter does nothing.  I saw the same when trying to setup <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to open nautilus.  The question is:

- what is this little box?
- what is it supposed to do?
- how can I remove it and use my keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Its the search box -- it happens in multiple programs, including Nautilus, and indicates the text you're searching for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for the fact, the shortcut to lock your screen is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, (at least that's the default 12.04 settings).

The little box is part of the Nautilus package and it is supposed to quickly highlight items that matches your "search items".

One possible way to disable that box is to actually disable the file manager handling the desktop. To disable it, install gnome-tweak-tool and disable it from there.

[image]

Comment: I overrode the default settings so that it would match windows.  Guess I should just go back.